# Set sharing intent using icon in action bar

Tags: android, share

I want to share the website that the user is viewing in the webview in my app, however any of the tutorials I have followed, it just isn't working. I can get the icon to load in the action bar but it doesn't click. I have had onclick listeners implemented and nothing so far. The app is only meant for ICS or higher so it doesn't need to be backwards compatible with older androids. The code I am putting up is before any share icon is implemented as I want to do it from scratch or to see if anyone has any ideas to what I can do

```
   public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView = null;
    private EditText mInputUrl = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String thesite = intent.getStringExtra(MainPage.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

mInputUrl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_url);
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String baseurl = "http://";
          String url = baseurl + mInputUrl.getText().toString();
          mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    });

mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.loadUrl(thesite);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

final Activity MyActivity = this;
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
     }
 public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
 {
  //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
  MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
  MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

  // Return the app name after finish loading
     if(progress == 100)
        MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
 }
 });
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
 myWebView.goBack();
 return true;
 }
 // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
 // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case android.R.id.home:
    // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
    // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
    // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
    // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
    //
    // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
    //
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**Edit**

I have used this code to try and get it working, however when I go to click the icon it doesn't do anything at all.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public final boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_share:
        shareURL();
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void shareURL() {
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mWebView.getUrl());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share This!"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. It was rather simple in the end.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public final boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_share:
        shareURL();
}
if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_item_refresh){
    mWebView.reload();
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void shareURL() {
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mWebView.getUrl());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share This Website!"));
}


}
```

This also allowed me to have a refresh button too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any override for onCreateOptionsMenu(..), are you sure you have added your ActionItems? Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html.

Ali.

Comment: I have when I tried it. This is the stage before, I was kind of hoping someone could give me an example possibly