# (FAB) Floating Action button with (Share Provider ) on webview app

Tags: android, facebook, webview, share, whatsapp

I want to use the android floating action button (FAB)  on my webview as a share action button >> to share current url to ( facebook - whatsapp ....etc )

here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//initializing webview
private WebView mwebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works for me ..

[How to activate "Share" button in android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167701/how-to-activate-share-button-in-android-app)

also check this if you want to use ( action bar buttons ) for sharing and refresh

[Set sharing intent using icon in action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145216/set-sharing-intent-using-icon-in-action-bar)